# I am trying to minimize a piecewise function using cvxpy

Tags: cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming

I want to minimize a

```
piecewise f(x) : 
as-bx,       x=>s+c
-bx,         x<=c
a(x-c)-bx,   c<=x<=c+s
```

I used Lagrangian multiplier and reformulate the problem:

```
f(x)=(as-bx1)y1 +(-bx2)y2+(a(x3-c)-bx3)y3

s.t:     x=>(s+c)y1
         x<=cy2
         cy3<=x<=(c+s)y3
         x1+x2+x3 =G
```

I used cvxpy and ECOS_BB solver but I get "PRIMAL INFEASIBLE (within feastol=8.8e-09)."

could anyone please help me to print the solver first iteration solutions and any comment on how can I overcome the infeasibility situation.

Comment: What coefficients are you using? a, b, c, s?